# clf.fit(X, y) not running with small values - fit() never completes - potential sklearn bug : Data Science

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, scikit-plot

This is not a fix my code question.(code works but not for the data used).
This question directly relates to the sklearn fit() function call as a technical enquiry.

Module call below.

```
 from sklearn import svm 
 svm.SVC.fit(X,y)
```

The code should fit the data (links provided below)

Resulting in a plot like the below image:
[image]

Looking for an expert opinion on performance or bug issue with the below code, 
please note the code runs but its the data I am running through it. When I pass in a log based, t-SNE the model just will not fit, I have ran it for hours and it should complete in seceonds.

Things I have tried: Waiting hours for it to complete
                     Spun up a box and paid google for a beasty box

I am begining to think that this may have something to do with all the floats being so small. However the float32 constraint should make this ok. Would really appreciate any advice or ideas.

data I am using available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xcelsiorbosi/data/master/data.csv) (X)

the corresponding y values can be grabbed [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xcelsiorbosi/uniEx4/master/y.csv)

```
print ("start")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix  
from sklearn import manifold, datasets, decomposition, discriminant_analysis

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,normalize=False,title='Confusion matrix',cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')


print ('read packages')
########################################    Log data    ########################################\

# df = pd.read_csv('logValuesOfWineData.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
# y = df['qualityBand'].values.astype(int)
# y = y.values
# subdf = df[[ 'Logfixed_acidity', 'Logvolatile_acidity','Logcitric_acid', 'Logresidual_sugar', 'Logchlorides',
#        'Logfree_sulfur_dioxide', 'Logtotal_sulfur_dioxide', 'Logdensity',
#        'Logsulphates', 'Logalcohol']]
# y = df['qualityBand'].map({1: 1, 2:2, 3:3})
# # removed free sulfar, rewsidual sugar, volatile acidity looks too normal
# # subdf = df[[ 'Logdensity','Logalcohol']]
# X = subdf.values

########################################    normal data    ########################################

# names = ['fixed_acidity', 'volatile_acidity', 'citric_acid', 'residual_sugar',
#        'chlorides', 'free_sulfur_dioxide', 'total_sulfur_dioxide', 'density',
#        'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol']


df = pd.read_csv('winequalityN.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
y = df['qualityBand'].values.astype(int)
# y = y.values
subdf = df[['fixed_acidity', 'volatile_acidity', 'citric_acid', 'residual_sugar',
       'chlorides', 'free_sulfur_dioxide', 'total_sulfur_dioxide', 'density',
       'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol']]

y = df['qualityBand'].map({1: 0, 2:0, 3:1})
X = subdf.values


print ('read data')
##################################  PCA      ######################################################
# X = subdf.values

# print ('about to PCA')
# X_pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
# X = X_pca

kk = pd.read_csv('test.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
X = kk.values
# kk = pd.read_csv('dfX_pca_Normal.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
# X = kk.values

print ('finished PCA')
##################################  X_tsne     ######################################################
# X_tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, init='pca').fit_transform(X)
# X = X_tsne
# kk = pd.read_csv('dfX_tsne_log.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
# X = kk.values
# kk = pd.read_csv('dfX_tsne_Normal.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
# X = kk.values
##############################################################################################

y = df['qualityBand'].map({1: 0, 2:0, 3:1})
y = y.values
print ('started')

# need cross val 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)

# # we create 40 separable points
# np.random.seed(0)
# X = np.r_[np.random.randn(20, 2) - [2, 2], np.random.randn(20, 2) + [2, 2]]
# Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20

# fit the model
# Model 1
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability = True)


print ('about to fit')
clf.fit(X, y)

print ('fit')
print ('model fit')


# get the separating hyperplane
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]

# plot the parallels to the separating hyperplane that pass through the
# support vectors
b = clf.support_vectors_[0]
yy_down = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])
b = clf.support_vectors_[-1]
yy_up = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])

# plot the line, the points, and the nearest vectors to the plane
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
plt.plot(xx, yy_down, 'k--')
plt.plot(xx, yy_up, 'k--')

plt.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1],
            s=80, facecolors='none')
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)


class_names = ['0','1']



plt.ylabel('PCA 1')
plt.xlabel('PCA 2')
plt.title('Transformed Support Vector Machine {1: 0, 2:0, 3:1}')
plt.axis('tight')




plt.show()
clf.predict(X_test)
probas = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  


print (classification_report(y_test, y_pred))


import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# y_pred = clf.predict(X_train)  

# y_true = # ground truth labels
# y_probas = # predicted probabilities generated by sklearn classifier


skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_test, probas)
# plt.show()
print (classification_report(y_test, y_pred))


# Compute confusion matrix
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()

plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names,
                      title='SVM Line: Confusion matrix, without normalization')

# Plot normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=True,
                      title='SVM Line: Normalized confusion matrix')

plt.show()



print("Accuracy", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))


print ('finito')
```

Comment: Without `kernel='linear'`, I am able to run it easily. Even with `kernel='linear'` and standardizing your data, I am able to run it. Just not ending with the original data.

Comment: Yeh ok,
It uses 'rbf' by default. 
Thats my point though why wont it run a linear kernel with that data it doesnt make any sense, I think I traced it to a numpy float indexing issue. 

Thanks for your help!!
I really wanted a linear a linear model and have had to re-write this in tensorflow

Comment: I found that its an optimisation problem within sklearn. Linear model equivalent in Tensorflow completed training under 1 minute.